# How to Generate a LTPA token from the Application that has been deployed in Web Sphere Application Server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, websphere, openldap, ltpa

I have a Spring Application, That authenticates the user name and password, And uses the JWT token for the SSO, I have deployed it in the Web Sphere Application Server, (**I have used the WAS 9 )I need the application to generate the LTPA token so that it can be used to authenticate the other application which is deployed in another web sphere application server, in the IBM Documentation, However the issues is. I am not aware where it needs to be added in the project. Or do I need to do anything needful. I have enabled the LTPA from the Security>> Global Security and enabled the SSO as well. I am aware that the generation is automated, But as the application needs to create the LTPA token for specific user. And it needs to be redirected to the URL of the other application, Which has the same domain name as well, The issue remains, What are the modification that I need to do in order for the application to generate the LTPA token and send it to the application that is deployed in other WAS server. And can I use the restapi for it. OR can be added in the URL, or use cookies.

Thank you in advance.